# How to use fullcalendar headerTitle outside of <Fullcalendar :options="calendarOptions"/>

Tags: vuejs3, fullcalendar, nuxtjs3

I am using fullCalendar in my nuxt3 project, where I need to create a custom header for the calendar. I am not able to show te header title of calendar:

[image]

This is my template where I tried to access the title:

```
<div class="current fw-bold">{{ calendar.view.title }}</div>
```

But it is only working when the component renders - this means it only shows the initial month and year and is not updating when we change to a new date with the next and prev buttons.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you include `title` in the [header toolbar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar) settings, fullCalendar will automatically update it for you. You can control the format of that title date using the [titleFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat) option. I don't know why you created your own header?

Comment: Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvOqpXm

Comment: I know we have title in calendar header and we can adjust the position and format. But in my requirement there are lots of fields and it would be totally different from the original one, so I need to access the title value only, I have already handled the other things.

Comment: Ok. So to make sure you can update the header from its initial value you would need to monitor fullCalendar to see when the view or the date range has changed. I'd expect you could use the `datesSet` callback for that, or maybe `viewDidMount` would be better. Then you can get the latest information about the calendar's display and use it to update your HTML. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet for details.